# how to sort varchar numeric columns by DESC or ASC?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, natural-sort

I write ...

```
ORDER BY column ASC
```

but my column is `VARCHAR` and it sorts wrong like `1, 10, 2`, instead of `1, 2, 10`.

How can I do it to sort like `1, 2, 10`?

Comment: "it sorts wrong": Actually that's *correct* sorting for a VARCHAR column. You need to convert the value to a numeric type. What database and version are you using?

Comment: do you have decimals in the column or just ints?

Comment: sorry I don't know how to check DB version

Comment: Always 2 decimal places?

Comment: It's called a "natural sort" when dealing with string data, which SQL doesn't support.  There are database specific ways to perform "natural sorting", and duplicate SO questions that already address this...

Comment: no... sometimes there is, sometimes not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
order by 
   cast(column as float)
```

Notes:

- Assumed you only have numbers in the columns. No "fish" or "bicycle"
- empty strings CAST to zero

Edit: For MySQL. [You can not cast to float](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=34564)

```
order by 
   cast(column as decimal(38,10))
```

Comment: BTW: as I know FLOAT is working maximum with 7 chars... like 999.99, but there can be more

Comment: @Daniel: What do you mean by that? Of course it gives something. You do know that you need SELECT etc in front of the ORDER BY?

Comment: @Daniel: float is 15 significant figures. real is 7. Easy to check on MSDN before posting that

Comment: $table = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE status = 'go' ORDER BY cast (amount AS float) DESC LIMIT 10"); shows nothing

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'float) DESC LIMIT 10' at line 1

Comment: @Daniel: you are using mysql: I will correct my syntax. Note you are limited what you can CAST to in MySQL. And you have no error trapping in your code.

Comment: the edited version worked very well thanks... and what does it mean 38,10?

Comment: @gbn Can you tell me why `cast(column as DECIMAL(38,10))` doesn't return error as `cast(column as INT)` does? It works for me.. :D

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi: SQL Server or MySQL?

Answer (score 3):

You can cast to int...

```
order by cast(column as int)
```

**DEMO**

```
DECLARE @q as table(
name varchar(50),
columnn varchar(10)

)
insert into @q
VALUES('one','1'),('one','10'),('one','20'),('one','3'),('one','2'),('one','20')


select * from @q order by cast  (columnn as int) desc
```

prints

```
-------------------------------------------------- ----------
one                                                20
one                                                20
one                                                10
one                                                3
one                                                2
one                                                1
```

So, Daniel, yes, it works :)

**UPDATE**:

```
order by cast(column as decimal(20,6))
```

Will cast the column values to decimal numbers with 20 digits max and 6 decimal places. Adjust it to your actual requirements.

Comment: I saw your answer appear and disappear hehe ;)

Comment: if You mean for example... "order by cast(column as int) DESC", sorry it doesn't work

Comment: @Daniel: give better sample data and schema place then. This will work with integers

Comment: @Daniel check my answer again. Provided an example.

Comment: @Daniel well you need to use your column's name instead of the word "column".

Comment: $table = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE status = 'go' ORDER BY cast (amount AS int) DESC LIMIT 10");

Comment: @Daniel It doesn't because only until NOW you cared to tell us that you don't have integers in the varchar column but rather decimal numbers. Look at gbn's answer. Simply cast to float (gd!)

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'float) DESC LIMIT 10' at line 1

Comment: @Icarus: it is MySQL. Can't CAST to float

Comment: on my example, 20 is the maximum number of digits and 6 is the maximum number of decimal numbers to the right of the comma.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
order by CAST(column as UNSIGNED)
```

Comment: i don't know why this has no votes when in fact it works perfectly fine. anybody can explain?

Answer (score 1):

i used this way
multiply it with one the query is :

> ORDER BY columnname * 1 ASC

Example: Table user have value with column value `[varchar(20)]`.
Then you can query it:

> SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY value * 1

After we multiply it **MySQL** will treat it like a number but  this way is not recommended for a heavy load.